# How do I use Enums in getters and setters?

Tags: java, enums

So what I am trying to do is this:

Write a User class

A User:

- has a username e.g 'fj3'
- has a userType which can be: 'user', 'editor' or 'admin'
- has a name e.g 'Francis'
- has a constructor which takes the username, userType and name as parameters
- has a getUsername() method
- has a getUserType() method
- has a getName() method
- has a setUserType() method which takes one of the user types as a parameter

My code so far:

```
public class User{

     public String id;
     public String userPermissions;
     public String actualName;

     public User(String username, String userType, String name){
         id = username;
         userPermissions = userType;
         actualName= name;
     }

    public String getUsername(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserType(){
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName(){
        return actualName;
    }

    public enum UserType{
       admin, editor, user;
    }

    public void setUserType(String input){
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work? I do not know how to make it so the only usertypes that can be chosen are admin, editor or user.

Comment: Validate the data? Use a known list of types?

Comment: _How should I do this in bluej?_ You do it in java, not bluej, bluej is just an IDE

Comment: You should rename `userPermissions` to `userType`.

Comment: If you're setting `id = username`, either change the field name in the class to `username`, or pass in `id`. And id and a username are different things, and your code pretends they're the same thing at the moment. Using a class-generated id might be even better, so that you can create a user and then as for its id after it's been created. The same problem exists for userPermissions/userType and actualName/name. `public User(String id, String userType, string userName) { this.id = id; this.userType = userType; this.userName = userName; }`. Now we have sensible code.

Comment: Using an enum is absolutely the right thing to do to restrict the user type to only one of a set of constants that are all known at compile time.  However, the Java convention for naming both static final fields and enum constants is to use ALL_UPPER_CASE with words separated by an underscore.  Because enum constants are otherwise indistinguishable from other identifiers, it is rather important to follow this convention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to change your types to this enum:

```
public class User {
     public enum UserType {
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
     }

     public String id;
     public UserType userPermissions;
     public String actualName;

     public User(String username, UserType userType, String name) {
         id = username;
         userPermissions = userType;
         actualName= name;
     }

    public String getUsername() {
        return id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName() {
        return actualName;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType input) {
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason that this doesn't work is because `userPermissions` is declared as type `String`.  It really should be declared as type `UserType`, but in order to store the enum as a String you need to invoke the name() or toString() method on the enum.

Comment: @scottb `userPermissions` is type `UserType`. In BlueJ you should be able to create a object using `("uname", UserType.ADMIN, "realname")`

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the original poster's data model, I didn't see that you had changed the type of userPermissions to UserType.

Comment: Thanks =) that explains that. Now it compiles but when I try to create an object using this class I'm failing- I'm not sure if it's my inputting the data wrong or what. The name and username are fine I think but when I try to inout usertype I get a message saying incompatible types if i try "admin" or error: cannot find symbol- variable admin if i try admin

Comment: Oh, I just tested that, you have to use `User.UserType.ADMIN`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have already declared an enum type to represent the possible values for userType, you've already gone a long way to solving this problem.

If you declare a variable of type UserType, then the only possible values must be one of the defined enum constants.

To restrict the input to your setPermissions method, all you have to do is change to the following:

```
public class User{

    public String id;
    public String userPermissions;
    public String actualName;

    public User(String username, String userType, String name){
        id = username;
        userPermissions = userType;
        actualName = name;
    }

    public enum UserType{
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType type){
        userPermissions = type.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and I get an error in my getUserType method saying "incompatible types" and highlighting the return userPermissions;. Does this need to be changed somehow too?

Comment: As written, the only way the method `setUserType(UserType type)` can fail is if (1) the instance field `userPermissions` is not declared as a String, or (2) if you are not passing an enum constant in your method call. Calls should look like: `setUserType(UserType.EDITOR);`.